# How do I convert a git repository folder into a regular folder?

Tags: git

If I want to turn a local git repository into a regular (non versioned) folder what do I have to do?

I've had an SVN project before and in that case I had to delete an SVN folder from every directory. I've read git has one project folder but after some searching it sounds like there is more to it.

PS I do not want to export a repository because not all the contents are checked in.

Comment: The settings are a hidden folder called `.git` at the root of the repository. You can just delete this folder... or simply not use Git to commit anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just delete .git directory and it will be all.

Actually, as far as a file manager (windows file explorer or nautilus etc) is concerned, a git repo is just a directory. Nothing to do.

Comment: If the directory was a nested git repository, might also need to also re-stage any current changes in the parent (now, only) git repo, like `git reset` then `git add .`, else it might still treat the directory that previously contained `.git` as a nested repo